# How do I add tasks to a Tokio event loop that is running on another thread?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

[I'd like to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279989/is-there-a-way-to-launch-a-tokiodelay-on-a-new-thread-to-allow-the-main-loop-t/54280186?noredirect=1#comment95826753_54280186) spin up a Tokio event loop alongside a Rocket server, then add events to this loop later on. I read [Is there a way to launch a tokio::Delay on a new thread to allow the main loop to continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54279989/155423), but it's still not clear to me how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the documentation states](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.21/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.handle):

> The returned handle can be used to spawn tasks that run on this runtime, and can be cloned to allow moving the `Handle` to other threads.

Here is an example of spinning up the event loop in one thread and having a second thread spawn tasks on it.

```
use futures::future; // 0.3.5
use std::{thread, time::Duration};
use tokio::{runtime::Runtime, time}; // 0.2.21

fn main() {
    let (shutdown_tx, shutdown_rx) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel();
    let (handle_tx, handle_rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    let tokio_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut runtime = Runtime::new().expect("Unable to create the runtime");

        eprintln!("Runtime created");

        // Give a handle to the runtime to another thread.
        handle_tx
            .send(runtime.handle().clone())
            .expect("Unable to give runtime handle to another thread");

        // Continue running until notified to shutdown
        runtime.block_on(async {
            shutdown_rx.await.expect("Error on the shutdown channel");
        });

        eprintln!("Runtime finished");
    });

    let another_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let handle = handle_rx
            .recv()
            .expect("Could not get a handle to the other thread's runtime");

        eprintln!("Another thread created");

        let task_handles: Vec<_> = (0..10)
            .map(|value| {
                // Run this future in the other thread's runtime
                handle.spawn(async move {
                    eprintln!("Starting task for value {}", value);
                    time::delay_for(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
                    eprintln!("Finishing task for value {}", value);
                })
            })
            .collect();

        // Finish all pending tasks
        handle.block_on(async move {
            future::join_all(task_handles).await;
        });

        eprintln!("Another thread finished");
    });

    another_thread.join().expect("Another thread panicked");

    shutdown_tx
        .send(())
        .expect("Unable to shutdown runtime thread");

    tokio_thread.join().expect("Tokio thread panicked");
}
```

```
Runtime created
Another thread created
Starting task for value 0
Starting task for value 1
Starting task for value 2
Starting task for value 3
Starting task for value 4
Starting task for value 5
Starting task for value 6
Starting task for value 7
Starting task for value 8
Starting task for value 9
Finishing task for value 0
Finishing task for value 5
Finishing task for value 4
Finishing task for value 3
Finishing task for value 9
Finishing task for value 2
Finishing task for value 1
Finishing task for value 7
Finishing task for value 8
Finishing task for value 6
Another thread finished
Runtime finished
```

The [solution for Tokio 0.1 is available in the revision history of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54612971/1).

See also:

- [How to run an asynchronous task from a non-main thread in Tokio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61292425/155423)

Comment: The overhead for calling `handle_rx.recv()` should be relatively small, correct? Just thinking if I should use `lazy_static` or if dynamic access would be sufficient.

Comment: Perhaps a larger issue for a general use case (including mine), how would one go about sharing the tx/rx channel between files? The obvious way is via a `pub static`, but `lazy_static` doesn't allow for destructuring a tuple, and the tuple's fields are private.

Comment: @jhpratt Yes, I'd expect the single transfer of the `Handle` to be very lightweight. I don't understand your other question; "files" aren't a meaningful unit here. You need to provide each thread with a copy of the `Handle` somehow, and that's going to vary based on how you spin them up.

Comment: Actually figured it out (sorta). What I ended up doing was creating a mutable static (`Option<Handle>`). It needs `unsafe`, but given the strict ordering of things, I don't see that as an issue. If the cloning becomes an issue, I'll certainly look into `Rc` and whatnot.

Comment: @jhpratt using a `static mut` is almost guaranteed to introduce undefined behavior into your program and you shouldn’t use it. You seem to be making it more complicated than it really needs to be.

Comment: this answer no longer compiles, i was told on irc that you can do this without channels with handles now

Comment: @JanusTroelsen updated. Neither answer requires channels **for spawning the task**. The channels are used to transfer the handle between threads and to tell the runtime when to exit. If you have a different organization, your code may not need either of those.