# How to run an asynchronous task from a non-main thread in Tokio?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

```rust
use std::thread;
use tokio::task; // 0.3.4

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        task::spawn(async {
            println!("123");
        });
    })
    .join();
}
```

When compiling I get a warning:

```
warning: unused `std::result::Result` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     thread::spawn(|| {
7  | |         task::spawn(async {
8  | |             println!("123");
9  | |         });
10 | |     })
11 | |     .join();
   | |____________^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
   = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
```

And when executing I get an error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'must be called from the context of Tokio runtime configured with either `basic_scheduler` or `threaded_scheduler`', src/main.rs:7:9
```

Comment: What is your actual goal here? Why are you trying to spawn that task on a different thread? I think the answer really depends on what you're wanting to do.

Comment: @Frxstrem I need to start another thread from a non-main thread (t), and the thread (t) should continue on. Before that, I used a thread pool. Something like https://repl.it/repls/AssuredWellmadeParentheses                                                             
Now I decided to replace the pool with async/await Tokio

Comment: The real question is: why are you mixing threads and tasks?

Comment: If you use tokio, it's better to use it everywhere. tasks are not threads, and cannot be spawned from anywhere, only from a thread managed by tokio. You might be able to use a tokio channel to communicate between the two, but that is a significant amount of extra work and a very different code structure

Comment: You need to get a handle to the runtime, which you can pass to the thread. You might have to manually create the runtime to be able to do this. The handle will then handle marshalling the task from the thread it is called on to the tokio worker thread.

Comment: I assume the non-main thread is created by something outside your control.

Answer (score 24):

The key piece is that you need to get a Tokio [`Handle`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.4/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html). This is a reference to a [`Runtime`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.4/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html) and it allows you to spawn asynchronous tasks from outside of the runtime.

When using [`#[tokio::main]`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.4/tokio/attr.main.html), the simplest way to get a `Handle` is via [`Handle::current`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.4/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.current) *before* spawning another thread then give the handle to each thread that might want to start an asynchronous task:

```rust
use std::thread;
use tokio::runtime::Handle; // 0.3.4

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let threads: Vec<_> = (0..3)
        .map(|thread_id| {
            let handle = Handle::current();

            thread::spawn(move || {
                eprintln!("Thread {} started", thread_id);

                for task_id in 0..3 {
                    handle.spawn(async move {
                        eprintln!("Thread {} / Task {}", thread_id, task_id);
                    });
                }

                eprintln!("Thread {} finished", thread_id);
            })
        })
        .collect();

    for t in threads {
        t.join().expect("Thread panicked");
    }
}
```

You could also create a [global, mutable singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423) of a `Mutex<Option<Handle>>`, initialize it to `None`, then set it to `Some` early in your `tokio::main` function. Then, you can grab that global variable, unwrap it, and clone the `Handle` when you need it:

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy; // 1.5.2

static HANDLE: Lazy<Mutex<Option<Handle>>> = Lazy::new(Default::default);
```

```rust
*HANDLE.lock().unwrap() = Some(Handle::current());
```

```rust
let handle = HANDLE.lock().unwrap().as_ref().unwrap().clone();
```

See also:

- [How do I add tasks to a Tokio event loop that is running on another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54612970/155423)
- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)
- [How to create a dedicated threadpool for CPU-intensive work in Tokio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61752896/155423)
- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)

Answer (score 10):

I have a job processing app that exposes a web API to add jobs and process them but the API request should not wait for the job to finish (it could take a while). I use Server-Sent Events to broadcast the job result. This means the main API server is executing inside `main` with `#[tokio::main]`, but where should I be running the job executor? In the job executor, I will have plenty of waiting: things like downloading. They will interfere with the web API server. The crucial question is how do I even start both executions in parallel?

In this scenario, you need to create a separate thread with  [`thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) inside which you will create a Tokio executor. The error you get is that inside your second thread, there is no Tokio executor (runtime). You need to create one manually and tell it to run your tasks. The easier way is to use the [`Runtime`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.23/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html) API:

```rust
use tokio::runtime::Runtime; // 0.2.23

// Create the runtime
let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();

// Spawn a future onto the runtime
rt.spawn(async {
    println!("now running on a worker thread");
});
```

In your main thread, an executor is already available with the use of `#[tokio::main]`. Prior to the addition of this attribute, the runtime was created manually.

If you want to stick with the async/await philosophy, you can use [`join`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.23/tokio/macro.join.html):

```rust
use tokio; // 0.2.23

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (_, _) = tokio::join!(start_server_listener(), start_job_processor());
}
```

This is why most answers are questioning your approach. Although very rare, I believe there are scenarios where you want an async runtime to be on another thread while also having the benefit to manually configure the runtime.