# How can I have a grace period between starting an asynchronous operation and waiting for its result in a loop?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I have a loop:

```
let grace = 2usize;
for i in 0..100 {
    if i % 10 == 0 {
        expensive_function()
    } else {
        cheap_function()
    }
}
```

The goal is that when it hits `expensive_function()`, it runs asynchronously and allows `grace` number of further iterations until waiting on `expensive_function()`.

If `expensive_function()` triggers at iteration 10, it could then run iterations 11 and 12 before needing to wait for the `expensive_function()` run on iteration 10 to finish to continue.

How could I do this?

In my case `expensive_function()` is effectively:

```
fn expensive_function(&b) -> Vec<_> {
    return b.iter().map(|a| a.inner_expensive_function()).collect();
}
```

As such I plan to use multi-threading within this function.

Comment: So you need the result only until you run into the if again ? So your two branch are totally independent ?

Comment: @Stargateur At the extreme, yes. But not ideally. This is code for calculating a bunch of productions in a game. On the last day of the month production is calculated for that month, now players might not notice if it is not done until the 2nd day of the next month (if time is passing quickly), this helps deal with the sort of stutter and time halting you might get otherwise as it runs this calculation. Hope that gives some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the expensive computation, store the resulting future in a variable, along with the deadline time to wait for the result. Here, I use an `Option` of a tuple:

```
use std::{thread, time::Duration};
use tokio::task; // 0.2.21, features = ["full"]

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let grace_period = 2usize;
    let mut pending = None;

    for i in 0..50 {
        if i % 10 == 0 {
            assert!(pending.is_none(), "Already had pending work");

            let future = expensive_function(i);
            let deadline = i + grace_period;
            pending = Some((deadline, future));
        } else {
            cheap_function(i);
        }

        if let Some((deadline, future)) = pending.take() {
            if i == deadline {
                future.await.unwrap();
            } else {
                pending = Some((deadline, future));
            }
        }
    }
}

fn expensive_function(n: usize) -> task::JoinHandle<()> {
    task::spawn_blocking(move || {
        println!("expensive_function {} start", n);

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));

        println!("expensive_function {} done", n);
    })
}

fn cheap_function(n: usize) {
    println!("cheap_function {}", n);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
}
```

This generates the output of

```
cheap_function 1
expensive_function 0 start
cheap_function 2
expensive_function 0 done
cheap_function 3
cheap_function 4
cheap_function 5
```

Since you did not provide definitions of `expensive_function` and `cheap_function`, I have provided appropriate ones.

One tricky thing here is that I needed to add the `sleep` call in the `cheap_function`. Without it, my OS never schedules the expensive thread until it's time to poll it, effectively removing any parallel work. In a larger program, the OS is likely to schedule the thread simply because more work will be done by `cheap_function`. You might also be able to use [`thread::yield_now`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.yield_now.html) to the same effect.

See also:

- [How to create a dedicated threadpool for CPU-intensive work in Tokio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61752896/155423)
- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)
- [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932137/155423)

Comment: What affect does `#[tokio::main]` have here? (I know of the crate being popular for async operations, but never used it) (look at the documentation for the macro, still not quite sure)

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light I encourage you to click the links I've provided at the end of the answer, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423).

Comment: On using `#[tokio::main]` I'm getting: `failed to resolve: could not find 'main' in 'tokio'
could not find 'main' in 'tokio'`

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light once you have clicked to the related question, the [`tokio::main`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.4/tokio/attr.main.html) text is a link to the documentation for it. The documentation includes the line *This is supported on feature="macros" only*. [How do you enable a Rust “crate feature”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58480205/155423)

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, I have some more stuff to consider and work out.